# MYSQL Auto increment to start at 0 for each foriegn key

Tags: mysql

We are writing a program for where table can have multiple inputs defined by an id which auto increments and a foreign key. For each entry into the table we want it to look like:

### | fk | ID |

### | 1     | 0  |

### | 1     | 1  |

### | 1     | 2  |

### | 2     | 0  |

### | 3     | 0  |

### | 3     | 1  |

And so on. Is this possible on the database end?

Comment: take one more column and assign it primary key and auto increment

Comment: ID is already assigned primary key but what is currently happening is the auto increment gives a unique value every time instead of starting back at 0 for the next foreign key. Is what you are saying that because id is set as a primary key the auto increment is forcing an original number for that column based on the whole table noddy?

Comment: This question pops every day. You don't reset auto increment, you don't make it go from zero, you just leave it be. Period. It's that simple. Auto increment is **not for your use**. It doesn't serve for your application logic. It has only one job - to give something unique to the table row. That's all. Just don't touch it and add another column that you maintain with triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

### pk | fk | id

1  | 1 | 0

2  | 1 | 1

3  | 2 | 2

pk is primary key column with auto increment.

Comment: Oh but you can only auto increment one column. That should be fixable just means weneed to change pretty much our whole program.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set your expected increment in DB side. You can try triggers or do some tricks in your insert query as Follows

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` (`fk `, `id`) SELECT '3', (SELECT count(`fk `) as n FROM `my_table` WHERE `fk ` = 3 )
```

Pass the fk value to query from your code.